# FileNotFoundException при использовании библиотеки PDFView

Tags: java, android, pdf, view

Использую данную библиотеку https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-pdfview для чтения PDF, но не получается все это запустить - выдает ошибку.

```
public class MaterialsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnPageChangeListener {
    PDFView pdfView;
    Integer pageNumber = 1;
    public static final String SAMPLE_FILE =  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/12345.pdf";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_materials);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        PDFView pdfView = (PDFView) findViewById(R.id.pdfview);
        pdfView.fromAsset(SAMPLE_FILE)
                .defaultPage(pageNumber)
                .onPageChange(this)
                .load();
    }
    @Override
    public void onPageChanged(int page, int pageCount) {
        pageNumber = page;
    }
}
```

Файл существует (скачивается из интернета), но приложение при создании формы крашится. Не подскажите, как эту штуку заставить работать? Что я не так делаю?

**Логи ошибки**

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/12345.pdf
at android.content.res.AssetManager.openAsset(Native Method)
at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:316) 
at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:290) 
at com.joanzapata.pdfview.util.FileUtils.fileFromAsset(FileUtils.java:33)
at com.joanzapata.pdfview.PDFView.fromAsset(PDFView.java:963) 
at developervision.ru.novgu.MaterialsActivity.onCreate(MaterialsActivity.java:34)
```

Добавил проверку `File file = new File(SAMPLE_FILE); if(file.exists())` но он её проходит, т.е. файл существует

**Файл манифеста**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Comment: Без указания ошибки (её логов) и конкретной строчки на коей она возникает помочь вам невозможно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас проблема в том, что вы пытаетесь грузить файл из `Assets` (внутренняя защищённая папка для файлов, поставляемых с приложением) методом `fromAssets`, тогда как он находится не там, а в корне устройства, т.е. там, куда вы его скачали. Таким образом вам надо пользовать метод `fromFile(File file)` вот так:

```
File file = new File(SAMPLE_FILE);
pdfView.fromFile( file )
            .defaultPage(pageNumber)
            .onPageChange(this)
            .load();
```

---

Также, может быть, у вас просто не добавлено разрешение в манифесте на чтение файлов.

Добавьте вот это

> `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

В корневой тег манифеста. Выглядеть должно примерно так:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    ...>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        ...>
           ....
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Добавлено, потому что я ещё предварительно скачиваю этот PDF

Comment: @T2skler, надо было это сразу в вопросе уточнить) И, будьте добры перенести это в вопрос, чтобы никого больше не вводить в заблуждение)

Comment: @T2skler, см. обновлённый ответ.

Comment: Большое спасибо, совсем упустил из виду, взял кусок кода из примера

Comment: @T2skler, пожалуйста)